# Copy a cell if another cell contains a specific text string

Tags: excel

I need some advise on a excel file I'm putting together. 
I want to have a cell copy the content from another cell in a different sheet if a third cell contains a specific text string.
I know it sounds confusing so to ellaborate.

Spreadsheet ALPHA on cell A3 should copy or reference the content in Spreadsheet BRAVO A3 if the cell D3 on spreadsheet BRAVO contains the text HOT.

Your expert insight is most appreciated.

Thanks in advanced ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy or reference cell A3 of ALPHA in cell A3 of BRAVO if D3 of BRAVO contains text "HOT" then try the below formula in BRAVO cell A3 :

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("HOT",UPPER(D3),1),0),ALPHA!A3,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Alpha!A3,

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hot", Bravo!D3)), Bravo!A3, "")

Answer (score 0):

Tried and Tested: Alpha A3 Cell formula:

For Case Sensitive Match:

```
=IF(EXACT(Bravo!D3,"HOT"), Bravo!A3,"Default")
```

For Case In-Sensitive Match:

```
=IF(Bravo!D3="HOT", Bravo!A3,"Default")
```